Is there a standard for labeling PCB jumpers by their function (enable or disable)?
For example, I have a circuit with different revisions that had to have two different voltage regulators. The original regulator needed a jumper pad cut to disable it, the other needed a solder pad bridged to disable it. Would the jumper pads be named on the silkscreen by the function that changing it performs, or by another standard for simply whether it is open or closed, or is default state? In other words, would you label both sets of pads "regulator disable" and regardless of whether you had to cut it or bridge it, changing from the default means performing that function (disabling in this case). Or is it supposed to be labelled "regulator enable" and infer in the first case cutting it would disable it? And then what of the second case where it is enabled with the pads open and you have to bridge it to disable it?

Reference designators are done out of courtesy for the person who has to troubleshoot issues. You're free to label anything however you want.


Is there a standard for labeling PCB jumpers by their function (enable
or disable)?

I doubt that there is some standard or rule that must be obeyed in these circumstances. Just be clear and use common sense. You should definitely make it clear that the two circuit boards are different revisions but, the labeling of a jumper is down to what you feel is fitting.
Of course if your industry has very tight rules about what you must do then take guidance but, generally, use what you feel is appropriate and what serves the purpose to which it is intended.

PCB layout is accurately referred to as "artwork" for a number of reasons:

It's drawn by an engineer.

An engineer is an artist working in a technical medium.  While the number of constraints might be higher and more scientific than for other artists, artists always work within some manner of constraint.  And this regularly includes business constraints, as in for-purpose and for-hire.  (Engineering might be more visible as for-hire than art is, but art as an industry is definitionally for-hire, after all.)  We might therefore classify these cases hierarchically, "artist" as the superset or general case, "engineer" as a subset or specific case.


It's graphical; in particular, industry-standard Gerber files are a to-scale monochrome vector graphics format, and industry-standard printing methods are equally binary (at best, halftone shading can be used, within dimensional constraints of the printing process).
Beyond the strict technical requirements, the engineer is free to make choices as they see fit; there is a vast space of free to low-cost* decisions one can explore in a real design.  Examples: component placement, grouping; trace placement, grouping, routing, orientation, choice of layers, etc.; extraneous (non-functional) copper, soldermask, silkscreen, etc.
As with any graphical artwork, it is a communication medium, with author(s) (including editors or reviewers, as applicable), and various audiences, intended and incidental.

*Just to make the point concrete: cost, in the sense of a heuristic cost function weighing against the requirements.  Some of the mentioned means of expression (component placement, trace routing) will have functional impact, though how much impact varies with requirements.  When those impacts are small or irrelevant, they become available as a means of expression.
There may be standards or requirements in specific domains, but in general, the standard is the function: how it's used, and who is using it.
There are certainly recommendations; consider IPC standards.  (Not to be contradictory: IPC is the industry trade group, who promulgate standards; the publications themselves are the standards, but what they standardize is usually not very much, actually.  They are mostly definitional -- useful perspective on how to work with and think about various things -- and recommendational ("you should/may do so-and-so").)  IPC-2221 would be the starting point here, though it's been a while since I read it and I'm afraid I don't recall if they say anything about silkscreen.
About Silkscreen
The technical minimum, is simply none at all: it has nearly zero electrical impact on the finished, assembled design.
Silkscreen is normally a porous deposit: pinholes and bubbles are common defects, and thickness varies with application method and surface geometry.  It therefore has no insulation value, or at least reliably so.  Perhaps if applied in double (or more!) layers, or with an approved process plus inspection steps, but, one quickly desires a better method -- conformal coating perhaps, or self-adhesive film, or insulating the overlaying components/wiring/etc. to the same end.
So, we must consider the audience we are authoring to.
Know The Audience
For production purposes, we might use component outlines to communicate approximate component size and orientation to assembly workers.  This facilitates placement (if manual, or during setup), optical inspection, and hand rework.  Designators, and perhaps even package type/size, or component value, might also be valuable information for this purpose, but beware the below considerations.
For testing purposes, we might provide outlines and designators, so that components can be referenced in notes, cross-referenced to schematics, and updates made.  Ultimately, changes discovered in prototype testing must be communicated to the design engineer (if changes are to be implemented in the board design itself), production/assembly (if by component substitution or rework), or both.
Note that if component values change, as a result of testing, later production changes, or if values are already intended to vary (assembly variants, making multiple PCBAs from a single PCB), it's a disservice to put values on the board itself!
Notation can even extend to the production/assembly step: component placement (non-functional), solder paste or component glue can be applied to the board to indicate variants.  For example, I've seen a laptop motherboard with a version/option table printed on it (silkscreen), notated with glue.
Similarly for repair purposes.  Designators, schematics and bill-of-materials must be communicated to servicepeople, at least to the extent component-level repair is intended.  If board-replacement repair is intended, then assemblies and wiring diagrams apply.
And then after that, there is the incidental audience.  What does your product look like, in general?  If it's in an opaque enclosure, the PCB might be irrelevant, outside of when... it gets smashed open or something.  (Would you ever be concerned what someone might think of it when it's been smashed open?  Probably not; but more to say, it's a possible interaction!)  More likely, someone curious opens it up, whether just because, or because it's dead and doesn't matter anymore (or, with intent to repair).  Might you want to communicate something useful in these cases?  Or silly, or profound?  Put a cartoon on the board, an Easter egg, a meme, a poem, whatever you like.
It goes deeper: you could hide Easter eggs within the PCB itself (multilayer design), where copper geometry is completely invisible from the outside, but the joke reveals itself when x-rayed (assembly inspection techs may also see this :) ), or reverse-engineered (e.g. sanding down the board layer by layer).  Maybe two people on the whole planet ever see your joke, outside of production (PCB fab workers).  It may be a small audience, but maybe you like playing to the long tail.
Similarly for potted designs, where peeling back the encapsulant might be somewhere between annoying and "could I just gouge out my eyeballs with a spoon instead?.."  Perhaps the PCBA, or several, or wiring, etc. is accessible only through various degrees of difficulty; same idea.  (I mean to be fair, a PCB is kind of a potted assembly of wires by itself.)  Anyone willing to go to that trouble is either very curious -- or very determined.  An inside joke, shared between competitors who know they're reverse-engineering each other's products, perhaps? :)
Or, perhaps PCB matter is more directly relevant to the design: a translucent or transparent enclosure might be chosen, or PCB stock used directly as the enclosure (in whole or in part).  Non-electrical PCBs are sometimes used as an easily-engineered, strong and dimensionally stable, high contrast front panel for cottage-industry sorts of instruments and products.  (Arguably, anything that's screen-printed metal could be seen as metal-core PCB, sans "printed circuit", in which case this includes a lot of brand names as well!)
Or perhaps the PCB is the product itself: demo/eval boards sometimes are released with fanciful artwork printed on them.  Sometimes using ENIG plating, soldermask and silkscreen (and perhaps additional layers of the latter) to express a gamut of colors, and render some quite provocative images.  I would say this is more common within the OSHW / hacking / demo scene than among brand-name products, but you occasionally see some rather nice looking boards from them as well.

What your describing is usually done with a note on the printed wiring assembly (PWA) drawing.  An example would be "Note 1: Add jumper from E1 to E2 if part number 12345 is installed at location U1".
I would not label the solder pads, pins, etc with anything more than the E1, E2 reference designation I used above.
It gets messy when you try to include the level of detail you were asking about in the silkscreen.
And note that whoever troubleshoots or assembles the board should have the assembly drawing at their disposal.
